# Quick release on my bike was opened without me knowing

Tags: personal-property

Last Friday (2/7/19) I just finished my 8 hour shift and happily pulled my bike from the break room. As I am biking home I notice that my front wheel isn't aligned properly with the forks and my front breaks aren't working properly (at first I believed them to be worn as I ride pretty hard and I'm heavy set (300 lbs, 6'1 ft tall)).
As soon as I get home I check my bike to see if anything was messed up on the way home and realize the quick release wasn't tightened properly (I usually close both quick release levers in the same position to meet a system I have when cleaning my bike every weekend) as the lever was in the open position and the bolt holding it in place was holding on by the last thread. 
The problem is this couldn't have been by accident as the quick release takes some force to open and close properly.
Also, someone would have told me if they "accidentally" did something to my bike.
 I've told my employer and they have reached back to me in any way shape or form. I take a route home that passes by freeway entrances and exits, if the front tire came off at any moment I surely could've been runover

Comment: Hi Jason - can you edit and clarify what your actual question is? This sounds like a scary situation but it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to ask us.

Comment: Are there any security cameras in the break room where your bike is stored?  If so, I would ask your company's security team to review the footage from that date.

Comment: Is it possible someone used the bike during the day?

Answer (score 1):

You learnt an important lesson, check your bike before riding it. It's not parked safe from idiots who may tamper with it.

Comment: Also, if anything seems wrong when you start riding it, stop and check it, right away.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, someone would have told me if they "accidentally" did something to my bike.

I wouldn't take this for granted. Not everybody is as honest as you think they are.

If you want to follow up on this, I suggest you ask if it's possible to check the security cameras to find out who is responsible of damaging your bike.

Also, as other answer suggests, it's very important to check your bike before taking a ride home, as a security measure (as one should also do when getting into your car... check tires, oil, etc.).

This will help you become aware of any tampering your bike may have suffered in time, and avoid possible accidents.